# Relabeling Duplicates in Excel of Cells in direct proximity

Tags: excel, duplicates

Apologies for the tile gore - was trying to be descriptive.

I have a large lab result data set, and it has been found that one analyte was screened for twice per sample and i need to capture both sets of results. This results in me having a table similar to below where Antimony is listed twice. Is there a way to automate something either to flag the instances where i have two rows like that or rename to antimony-1 and antimony-2? Since I have 300 sites screened for the same things, everything shows up as duplicate and i can't use the simple methods. The main trigger is the proximity to another row where everything is matching except the results.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you could use conditional formatting to highlight those rows and then filter on colour?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since the third column repeats for other sites everything is a duplicate. So i have 300 aluminum samples, so it will always come back as a Dupe. But i need to identify when a single location has 2 results for Antimony and differentiate them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you have the data in you screen shot starting in cell A1 (and Soil as your site) I'd add to columns the first combines Site & Element (Column F in my example):

```
=A1&C1
```

**Result**: SoilAluminium

In the column next to that I'd have a formula:

```
=F1&COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)
```

**Result** - SoilAluminium1, SoilAntimony1, SoilAntimony2 etc

**Note**: Pay Attention to the $'s

I hope that works

Comment: Thanks for that, I couldn't get it to work as intended the way you had it but it got me somewhere closer. When i tried your solution, SoilAntimony2 was listed twice; there was no SoilAntimony1 (likely because there always 2 hits for SoilAntionomy in the range). HOWEVER, i did get it to work by removing the $'s.

I ended up using the following 
=F1&COUNTIF(F1:F5,F1)
By not locking the range, i do get SoilAntimony1 and SoilAntimony2

Comment: You only want to lock the range of the first F1 in the count if - so you are always counting from the top row down to the row above the current cell. e.g if we were looking at the formula in row 4 it shoud be `=F4&COUNTIF($F$1 : F3, F4)`

Comment: Yeah i saw that, but it doesn't give me an Antimony1 then, it always counts 2 hits for SoilAntimony so both rows will be identified as SoilAntimony2. Though, just having that count works enough i guess as something for me to filter by and manually update